# MS Word pagination using Multiple wpf RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

My aim is to make a editor behave similar  to MS-Word.Wpf RichTextBox is a wonderful control for it.By placing it inside a ScrollViewer,we can make it editable.(Like a notepad).But I need MS-Word like pages.One effective way probably is to apply style to scrollViewer such that we create a look and feel of multiple pages on richtextbox but I dont know how to do it.What we are doing in the project is to use a documentViewer. Inside a FixedPage,create a Header(Canvas),Body(WpfRichTextBox),Footer(Canvas). And thus create multiple pages,and by subscribing to RichTextBox sizechanged event, we are manually doing the pagination i.e move the blocks from one page to another when height has changed. Do you see any better approach in doing this? Does using multiple richtextboxes hamper my performance?

Answer (score 2):

@WpfProgrammer This is the good approach I would say. Say if you have 1000s of pages then, there will definitely be a performance problem. For avoiding that problem, you need to do demand paging.

**Virtual Paging :**
 1. You need to construct a page table, which will contains pages. Each page will contains information about the controls, images, their positions, dimension and Styles for the page. [All serializable data]

 2. Virtual Pages - You need to
    de-serialize all the data for the
    page and create a page with
    RichTextBox. Virtual Pages are
    nothing but, pre-cached pages that
    are going to be rendered. Say for
    example. If I'm in 1st page. Then,
    I'll de-seriealize next 3
    consecutive pages and have them in a
    collection. Then, repeat this
    procedure for consecutive page
    movements. Adding some logic using
    Most Frequently Used collection. It
    will be fast enough. In the case of
    1000's of pages. You can collapse
    those non-dirty or never visited
    pages. That could yield little more
    performance. If performance is far
    more concern for low hardwares.
    Then, you should consider
    cleaning.
 
3. Cleaning -
    Cleaning is the process of
    identifying LFU pages and remove
    them. This would be very helpful if
    performance is more pronounced.

Comment: thanks a lot for the page Virtualization approaches. For me ,the maximum pages per editor will not exceed more than 50. And may be 2 to 3 editors will be launched,but I think virtualization does indeed improve the overall performance. The challenge I see is the pagination, although I have a basic algorithm for it. Moving blocks from one richtextbox to another and even flowing the content up during the delete operation is a challenge.And doing virtualization in this scenario is also tricky.Can there be no straightforward way of showing the richTextBox pages like MS Word?

Comment: I am listening to richTextBox size changed event and pushing the blocks from one rtb to another and this process repeats for all rtb's.And during the delete,on the page where delete occurs, I add all the blocks from subsequent rtb's from bottom to this page so that they again are readjusted accordingly.

Comment: 1) "Moving blocks from one richtextbox to another and even flowing the content up during the delete operation is a challenge" - This is layouting. It needs to be done in that way. 2) "Can there be no straightforward way of showing the richTextBox pages like MS Word" - As far as I think of, there is no special way.

Comment: I still believe having a single rtb in scroll viewer and playing around with the content template to show a border such that it illusions a page is a better way. But its some challenge though. I think Telerik rtb ooes something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Tameem
Set the min height,width of the richTextBox to A4 size(lets say). Subscribe to RichTextBox Size Changed event.As soon as the content exceeds,this event gets fired.Then I take the last block of previous page and push it to the first block of next page.(Remember if page doesnot exist, you need to create new page then add it as first block).And also the focus should be changed to the new page.(because if you press enter at the last RTB, you expect the focus to be there in the new page.).When the user deletes a block in some page(say 2nd),then you need to add all the blocks of bottom pages to this page,so that our pagination logic will push the blocks down again and adjust. I can share some piece of code if you need further help.